# What is the name of a half wall with posts on top that divides a space into two?

Tags: terminology, architecture, wood

I am looking for specific terminology around a half wall that acts as a divider to split a space into two separate uses. The top half of this features a series of wooden posts. It essentially resembles a balustrade except is not for stairs.

Is there a specific name for this?

Here are a few examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think that the wall part is called `pony wall`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non jargon terminology (i.e. non scientific architectural) would be *permanent room divider*  or *wall divider* or plain divider.

Probably the proper architectural terminology is  **[mullion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullion)** is a vertical element that forms a division between units of a window or screen, or is used decoratively

[image]

*Figure:  Mullion (image source: Wikipedia)*

---

In French you mint find it as *paravent*, which comes from the latin *paravento* (which translates for the wind).

The use of *permanent* is to separate what you are looking for from room dividers like

[image]

*Figure: room divider source:[vkf-renzel.com](https://www.vkf-renzel.com/room-divider-lea-with-wooden-slats-80-0720-5.html)*

Some architectural terms:

- **Cancellus (plural: Cancelli)** Barriers which correspond to the modern balustrade or railing, especially the screen dividing the body of a church from the part occupied by the ministers hence chancel. The Romans employed cancelli to partition off portions of the courts of law.
- **Muntin** A vertical or horizontal piece that divides a pane of glass into two or more panes or lites in a window.
- **railing** (also related handrail  and banister)

[image]

*Figure: Railing (source : [www.houzz.in](https://www.houzz.in/photos/horizontal-deck-railing-in-bloomfield-hills-phvw-vp%7E54828788))*

- (JimClark also suggested) ***Partition*** is another word that can refer to the vertical wall in a room. (This is something that I also thought of, but -*initially*- I decided not to include because in my mind partition refers to the horizontal spaces that are created by the vertical column).

Comment: Would there be a word or phrase for the top part with the sequential posts? I really like the conciseness of "balustrade" because in one word you know it is a series of posts, but balustrade does not make sense in this case?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you question. Are you asking about the lower half of the divider?

Comment: My original question concerns the entire wall/divider, but I would also like to be specific about the top part. If there isn't a term that captures a room divider with a balustrade like piece on top of the half wall then I suppose I would be interested in a term to further describe the room divider.

Edit: For the additional terms you have included above, I don't think they would apply to the example images would they, they are more specifically for a balustrade?

Comment: the balustrade indeed indicates a wall of vertical elements, however to me the difference is that  ***railing*** is a fence or barrier consisting of one or more horizontal rails and vertical supports while ***balustrade*** is a row of balusters *topped* by a rail, serving as an open parapet, as along the edge of a balcony, terrace, bridge, staircase, or the eaves of a building (so its always the lower part). Railing seems a more generic term (to me).

Comment: To answer your question about the vertical parts, IMHO *mullions* is the more appropriate term. So the whole thing would be a **wall divider with mullions**

Comment: I'll add Partition.

Comment: I'll add "Dwarf Wall" although these are usually external and topped by glass